# SwiftUI: Transparent part of the View and text

Tags: swiftui

Spending a few days playing around with different modifications and stacks I got stuck in achieve transparent part of the View and text. Goal is made views from code example with `.purple` color is transparent and they should be background gradient color like in expected result.

**Code example:**

```
struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.mint, .cyan], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            HStack(spacing: -20) {
                ZStack() {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                }
                ZStack() {
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(.purple, lineWidth: 5)
                        .background(Circle().fill(.white))
                        .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    VStack() {
                        Text("108")
                        Text("Days")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.purple)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would do this with the following extension:

```
public extension View {
    @inlinable
    func reverseMask<Mask: View>(
        alignment: Alignment = .center,
        @ViewBuilder _ mask: () -> Mask
    ) -> some View {
        self.mask {
            Rectangle()
                .overlay(alignment: alignment) {
                    mask()
                        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this on any view to *subtract* from it. In your example the right circle would look like this:

```
Circle()
    .fill(Color.white)
    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
    .reverseMask {
        VStack() {
            Text("108")
            Text("Days")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cameron has a great answer and it should be accepted. Based on it here's how you can also make a "transparent" circle around the small circle

```
struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let bigCircleSize: CGFloat = 120
        let smallCircleSize: CGFloat = 75
        let borderWidth: CGFloat = 5
        let maskCircleSize = smallCircleSize + borderWidth
        let spacing: CGFloat = -20

        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.mint, .cyan], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: bigCircleSize, height: bigCircleSize)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 60))
                }
                .reverseMask {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: maskCircleSize, height: maskCircleSize)
                        .offset(x: bigCircleSize / 2 + spacing + smallCircleSize / 2)
                }

                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Circle().fill(.white))
                        .frame(width: smallCircleSize, height: smallCircleSize)
                        .reverseMask {
                            VStack() {
                                Text("108")
                                Text("Days")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public extension View {
    @inlinable
    func reverseMask<Mask: View>(
        alignment: Alignment = .center,
        @ViewBuilder _ mask: () -> Mask
    ) -> some View {
        self.mask {
            Rectangle()
                .overlay(alignment: alignment) {
                    mask()
                        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to make another mask on the big circle. Calculate the x-offset and you're good to go